# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context line 16

Tags: java, static

there is a error in line 16 of this code. something about static, cant figure it out, any ideas will help.

```
package sample1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class Sample1 {
    //main class

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Account acc1 = new Account("George", 1122, 1000, .015);



        System.out.print("The account holder's name: " + acc1.getname()
                + ". The annual interest rate: " + acc1.getrate(.015)
                + ". The balance: " + acc1.getbalance() + ". The monthly interest: "
                + acc1.monthlyInterest + ". All the transactions: "
                + acc1.getTransactions());
    }


    public class Transaction {

        private Date datetrans;
        private char type;
        private double amount;
        private double balance;
        private String description;
        char Withdraw = 'W';
        char deposit = 'D';

        public Transaction(Date newDateTrans, char newType, double newAmount,
                double newBalance, String newDescription) {
            datetrans = newDateTrans;
            type = newType;
            amount = newAmount;
            balance = newBalance;
            description = newDescription;
            datetrans = new Date();
        }

        Date getdatetrans() {
            return datetrans;
        }

        char gettype() {
            return type;
        }

        double getamount() {
            return amount;
        }

        String getdescription() {
            return description;
        }

        double getbalance() {
            return balance;
        }

    }




        public class Account {

            private int id = 0;
            private String name;
            private double balance = 0;
            private double rate = 0;
            private Date dateAdded;
            private ArrayList<String> transactions = new ArrayList();

            public Account(String newName, int newId, double newBalance) // this is where the error is, any ideas why it can be  {
                id = newId;
                name = newName;
                balance = newBalance;
                dateAdded = new Date();
            }

            int getid() {
                return id;
            }

            double getbalance() {
                return balance;
            }

            double getrate(double newRate) {
                return rate;
            }

            public void setid(int newId) {
                id = newId;
            }

            public void setbalance(double newBalance) {
                balance = newBalance;
            }

            public void setrate(double newRate) {
                rate = newRate;
            }

            String getname() {
                return name;
            }

            String getTransactions() {
                return transactions.toString();
            }

            Date getDateAdded() {
                return dateAdded;
            }
            double monthlyInterestRate;
            double monthlyInterest;
            String withdraw;
            String deposit;

            public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
                monthlyInterestRate = rate / 12;
                return monthlyInterestRate;
            }

            public double getMonthlyInterest() {
                monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
                return monthlyInterest;
            }

            String getDeposit() {
                return deposit;
            }

            void addtransactions(String deposit) {
                transactions.add(deposit);
            }

            String getWithdraw() {
                return withdraw;
            }

            void droptransactions(String withdraw) {
                transactions.remove(withdraw);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read up on inner classes.

Comment: don't nest classes unless there's a real need, that's the cause of your error here.

Comment: how will i do it then

Comment: `Class Transaction` was defined but never used.

Comment: Your line 16 is empty. Can you say which line is causing the error?

Comment: Account acc1 = new Account("George", 1122, 1000, .015);

Answer (score 1):

Move Transaction and Account into their own files separate from Sample1, but in the same package (with the same package declaration at the top, in the same directory as Sample1, with a filename matching the class name).

Nested class declarations create inner classes, which (unless marked as static) rely on having a reference to the outer class. They're a complexity you don't need here. (Alternatively you *could* add static to the inner classes' declarations, but it's better to keep things simple.)

Comment: i moved them into thier own files but i still get an error in this line

Comment: Account acc1 = new Account("George", 1122, 1000, .015);

Comment: @jose: your constructor for Account takes only 3 arguments, you're passing in 4.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested non-static class called `Account`.  This means that to create an instance of this class, you need to have an instance of the outer class which `Sample1` in this case.  You can fix it three ways.

1) Use an instance of the outer class

```
Account acc1 = new Sample1().new Account("George", 1122, 1000, .015);
```

2) or you could make the class static as it doesn't appear to need the outer class.

```
static class Account {
```

You could do the same for Transaction.

3) Don't use a nested class and move it up one level.  Your IDE will be able to do this refactor for you.

Unless you have a preference I would use option 2 as it has a minimum of changes and it is most likely this is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use non-static variable inside static because static varible memory are allocate first when the class is loaded .So with your code you are saying that the static main() method whose memory allocated at runtime  to create a instance of non-static . `Here Sample1 main function donot know Account class exist or not.`

To solve this issuue you have to put a static keyword on your class declaration ie on

```
static class Account{}
```

[OUTPUT](https://ideone.com/kBdZPO)